# Is it safe to downgrade libgl1-mesa-glx?

Tags: package-management, 13.04, downgrade

I am trying to install `qt-sdk` but get the following error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
qt-sdk : Depends: libqt4-opengl-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I was able to find the package in question:

```
libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx (= 9.1.1-0ubuntu3) but 9.2.0~git20130216.dd599188-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal is to be installed
```

When I open synaptic package manager and try to downgrade the package it tells me that several other packages will be removed. Some of these packages seem important and I am not sure if downgrading is a good idea. I am running Ubuntu 13.04 after upgrading from 12.10. I had the same issue with 12.10 and was hoping that an upgrade would solve it.

So how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Those packages which caused unmet dependencies problem are installed from a repository that is from other sources. So it isn't cause a problem. So those should be removed.

Try with this :

```
sudo apt-get remove libgl1-mesa-glx libqt4-opengl-dev && sudo apt-get install qt-sdk
```

If you want to use that version somehow, you need to find a repository that gives the `qt-sdk` also. You are lucky if you can find. But rare chance.